# FirebaseModelManager's isModelDownloaded() method gives download status as success but interpreter fails

Tags: android, firebase, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

I am using Firebase MLKIT to download a remotely hosted tensor flow lite model and then use in app for object detection.

And using the following documentation for reference
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models

Download is working correctly and I can see the downloaded file in app data but after checking if my model is downloaded(which results in success), whenever I try to create FirebaseModelInterpreter's instance, it gives error with the following stack trace

```
com.google.firebase.ml.common.FirebaseMLException: You are trying to use a remote model before downloading it. Please Download it first
```

Same flow works correctly only once when I start with fresh install but gives error if I start using model after app is force stopped.

Can anyone please help with that ?

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: I will try again with the updated Jetpack libraries and update if it works or not.